# How to setup domain DNS records for cPanel WHM

Tags: dns, cpanel, dns-servers, amazon-ec2

I'm a newbie on this kind of things. I've deployed a cPanel on an AWS instance but failed to set up my domain DNS records, private nameservers etc.

Let me explain the whole situation.

I'm currently using a dedicated server service from a provider. I wanted to cancel my service and create my own AWS EC2 instance with cPanel. I created the instance and installed cPanel successfully, but couldn't set up my domain DNS records. Currently, I'm able to connect to WHM via elastic IP that I pointed to the EC2 instance, but need to set up a domain.

Can anyone lead me to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: " but couldn't set up my domain DNS records."  Can you give more info about the problem? Is there an error?  Do you just no know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried going to your domain registrar and pointing `A` records from `example.com` and `www.example.com` to your EC2 instance's IP address? This will make visitors to your domain name connect directly to your EC2 instance. No reason to use custom nameservers unless you are using a third party DNS service.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DNS records of a domain using WHM

1. Log into WHM as an Administrator.
2. Scroll down to the DNS Functions section and click Edit DNS Zone.
3. Select the domain that you want to edit the DNS of and click the Edit button.
4. Make any changes to the DNS records that you need to.